# X-Ray Paginate filter by text

Tags: node.js, x-ray

I am using x-ray to scrap a webpage with pagination. Here are some HTML

```
<td align="center" style="font-size: 11pt;">
  <div class="paginate" style="font-size: 11pt;">
    <span class="disabled">Previous</span>
    <span class="current">1</span>
    <a href="link2.html">2</a>
    <a href="link2.html">Next</a>
  </div>
</td>
```

I would like to scrap by the `Next` button. But the web page example is scraped by it's class name.

```
x('https://blog.ycombinator.com/', '.post', [{
  title: 'h1 a',
  link: '.article-title@href'
}])
  .paginate('.nav-previous a@href')
```

I would like to know how can I paginate by choosing the link in the `Next` button?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would write a custom parser, that will fit your needs best.

Comment: @Lazyexpert I guess you are right, I try to be lazy by using x-ray. But it seems it won't fit so well. Originally I use request + cheerio but I am trying to scrap sub pages (totally 4 layers) as well. Scraping 4 layers are slow sequentially, do you know how can I convert that into parallel requests?

Comment: you can use Promise.all, you can use async.parallel or again, make custom solution based on callbacks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter by text

```js
.paginate('.paginate a:contains(Next)@href')
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help you write this in paginate

```
.paginate('.paginate > li.current + a > a@href')
or
.paginate('.paginate > li.current > a@href')
```