# pagination/paginate in node.js xray, from current page to the others

Tags: node.js, npm, pagination, x-ray

I have a problem, for my school project I need to scrape image from Ikea's website, the pagination part of the website is here:

```html
 <div id="pagination" class="pagination">
  <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="active">1</a>
  <a href="/cn/en/search/?query=green&amp;pageNumber=2">2</a>  
  <a href="/cn/en/search/?query=green&amp;pageNumber=3">3</a>
  <a href="/cn/en/search/?query=green&amp;pageNumber=4">4</a>
  <a href="/cn/en/search/?query=green&amp;pageNumber=5">5</a>
  ...
  <a href="/cn/en/search/?query=green&amp;pageNumber=35">35</a>  
</div>
```

I referenced this spread, [filter by text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885793/x-ray-paginate-filter-by-text), `.paginate('.active ' + '.pagination a:contains(pageNumber)@href')`, but it doesn't work.

Any leads?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the href attribute of the sibling to the active page:

```
.paginate('.pagination .active + a@href')
```